# How can i create COM (in C++) server in VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, com

recently i want to create some COM Servers for my study project, i can use DLLs but i want to try COM. I'm new to this, i wonder if any one can provide some information about creating COM Server (in VS2010), thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSDN would be good starting point:

[Walkthrough: Creating a COM Server Using a Text Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2wad1c0e%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)