# Error while using C++-DLL with vbs

Tags: c++, dll, vbscript

I have a C++-DLL with the following function:

```
    DLL void hello(void)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World!" << '\n';
    };
```

and a VBS-Script located in the same folder with the following code:

```
    Dim funcObj
    Set funcObj = GetObject("TERS-DLL.dll")
    funcObj.hello
```

My operating system is Windows 8.1.
When I'm running the vbs-file, I always get the error "File- or class name not found during automatisation operation: 'GetObject'", error code 0x800A01B0.
Why do I get this error, and what can I do to fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: "TERS-DLL.dll" is not the name of a COM object, it is the name of a file.  You didn't write a COM server, required to be able to call your code from vbscript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i create COM (in C++) server in VS2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201401/how-can-i-create-com-in-c-server-in-vs2010)

Answer (score 2):

`GetObject` is used to load Automation objects, but your DLL seems to be a regular (i.e. not Automation) DLL.

Comment: How can I create an automation dll then? I tried to switch to a COM dll, but I still can not call functions, I always get compile errors...